# Minimising Power BI Drillthrough Pages

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a page where a user selects a week and it gives them a weekly and Month to Date view .

There is a **weekly measure** using a calculate that gives you the weekly view and one that gives the Month to date picture thrrough a **Month to Date measure** .

The problem is that I need two drillthrough pages as adding the measure to the table gived the data the context and returns the correct records for the drillthrough . Fromn the weekly figure you go to the weekly drillthrough page and from the monthly figure you go to the Monthly drillthrough page .

2 drilltrough pages seems like an overhead when I have 7 weekly weekly measures and 7 monthly measures in a table . Is there any way of reducing the drillthrough pages required ? Currently I am counting 14 drillthrough pages .

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is using calculation groups. Do you have access to tabular editor and are you comfortable creating calculation groups?

Comment: How will that reduce the number of drillthrough pages ? It will make building measures faster but dont understand how that will reduce the drillthrough pages required for each weekly or monthly measure

Comment: It is a trick to workaround the fact that drill through ignores filter context when using calculate in a measure. I might be misunderstanding your problem though. Can you share some screenshots as it isn't 100 percent clear.